# How to update record from grid with row editing active?

Tags: extjs, grid, record

I have a problem with `rowediting` plugin in `grid`.

I have a `grid` with 5 `columns` and only 1 column has an editor. I am using `rowediting` plugin.

My editor is a `textfield` and I have a change listeners. Every time this `textfield` is changed, I need to update another column value but this is done when I finish the edition (by pressing Enter key).

I use reconfigure method from store, the `rowediting` is cancelled and  don't want this behaviour.

How I can update my grid keeping the row edition?

Comment: Can you provide some of your code or a fiddle so that we can replicate the issue?

Comment: What are you using the reconfigure method for ? As I understand reconfigure a store makes that it is no longer the same store ( like if you modify the model ). As such it is expected that the editing is interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, something like this

```
if (field.getKey() == field.ENTER) {
    var record = editor.ownerCt.ownerCmp.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0],
        store = editor.ownerCt.ownerCmp.getStore(),
        newValue = editor.getValue();

    // enter key pressed
    if (record) {
        record.set("name", newValue);
        record.set("fullname", newValue + ' Simpson');
        record.commit();

        store.load();
    }
}
```

---

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hdv)